# Using Jump diffusion model to find expectation

Tags: probability-distributions, stochastic-processes

[image]

For this question I'm not able to understand how they got from the second line to the third. So not able to understand how they squared the term in the expectation and then simplified to get the terms without the expectation in the third line.

If for example we were asked to compute E(Xt^3) how then would we have gotten that answer by cubing the terms in the expectation sign. Would we have gotten sigma cubed t + n delta cubed + (mu t +n aplha)^3?

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint**:
$$E[X^2] = \text{Var}[X]+(E[X])^2\tag{1}$$
You may be more familiar with this as
$$\text{Var}[X] = E[X^2] - (E[X])^2$$
which, when rearranged, gives $(1)$.